# How to share view between pages

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Ok, I have add/eddit pages in my application. I have the same view, only behaviour on app button click is different.

My AddEdit page has a button - when I navigate to AddEdit Page the Tapped event works.

```
public partial class AddEdit
{
    //...

    private void Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
       //....
    }
}
```

But when I navigate to Add Page that inherits (both in class and xaml) AddEdit I can see the button but the button is not working (Event does not fire - can anyone know why?)

```
public partial class Add : AddEdit
{

    public Add () : base()
    { 
       //....
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope - Add is constructio of Add Page

Comment: Haven't tried it, but: This shouldn't work, als xaml is not meant to be inherited. If you check the generated files (Add.g.i.cs and Add.g.cs) you should see how generated fields are attached to different properties. All in all: Do not "inherit" Xaml.

Comment: Ok - thanks for the tip.